# Conditionally index types with union (getting T[K] where K may not be a key of all types)

Tags: typescript

Given a union of two (or more) types, I need to get an "index type" of a property that may only exists on one of the types:

```
type A = {
    one: 'a' | 'b'
}

type B = {
    two: 'c' | 'd'
}

type Both = A | B;

type X = Both['two'];
// expected: 'c' | 'd' | undefined
// actual: Error: Property 'two' does not exist on type 'Both'.
```

I understand why this is happening in the above code, but it seems like there should be some way to get "expected" result.

I tried conditional types, but ultimately couldn't figure it out...

Comment: you can probably utilize the `Extract` built-in. something like `Extract<Both, { two: any }>["two"]`

Comment: oh nice... that it's it pretty close, returning type `'c' | 'd'` but is still missing the `undefined` (which would required to reflect that an actual index into the object with the given key could result in `undefined`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type A = {
    one: 'a' | 'b'
}

type B = {
    two: 'c' | 'd'
}

type Maybe<T, K extends string> = T extends {[P in K]?: unknown} ? T[K] : undefined
type Both = Maybe<A | B, 'two'>
// 'c' | 'd' | undefined
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=32&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oHsB2EBcUA5AIaFQA+RARoSgL4oqiRQBCCyaGwA7pgYQDGZSoQAmtBk3DQAssRBUIAHgAqAGigBpKBAAewCNjEBnKCeAAnAJbYA5gD4Oq3QaOnkAbQAKUW9oBdAH4CAFdsAGtsTB5sOiggqFVPLQCoMOMIADNbCDFpFlZMYAALDnlFFThKVk1CXkxCBxQAehaiYQoiCS7wsWzc-KA)

Comment: fantastic!  exactly what I was looking for.  I tried something very similar, but didn't think to use `Record<K, unknown>`.

FYI: I think your previous answer was slightly better:  `type TwoProp = Maybe<Both, 'two'>`

Comment: it's working for me with no undefined :https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAgjAvDA3sGGYHsB2UBcMA5AIZEwA+xARkcAL7BPjQwBCSq6muBxAxuSpEAJnUwwQAdyyFSQmnUahIsNlhAALTgipsA3ExWsAsiTDUoAHgAqAGhgBpGFAAeIKDhEBnGN5AATgCWOADmAHycNi7unj4YAEpQ-FgBIlaODgCuOADWOFhSOJEA-DA2ANqOALowhDkiUABmIVAixrAA8nicZhbW6loORLxE4R3lMr3mllaDmsPSWGMTAHK80-1zGgvEBXhjQA

Comment: I am not sure, you can can writing `type Both = Maybe<A | B, 'two'>`, but for me it sometimes bugs.

Comment: ya it's actually not working in my solution for some reason, which is a bit more complicated

Comment: ah, if the property is optional it breaks: `one?: 'a' | 'b'`... interestingly, if you do `one: 'a' | 'b' | undefined` it works :/

Comment: Updated answer with a fix that support optional properties